# with Acts As Taggable On, How can I keep quotation marks in my tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

Here is my code.  For some reason when adding tags with quotes, only every other one retains the quotes (My delimiter is tab):

```
>user.tag(domain, :with => "\"one\"\t\"two\"\t\"three\"", :on => :tags)

>domain.owner_tags_on(@user, :tags)
 => [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 360, name: "\"two\"">, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 365, name: "one">, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 377, name: "three">]
```

result when rendered

> "two"
>   one
>   three

I've tried placing single quotes around tags with quotes, but that results in every other tag having a single quote.

I am confused as to why my attempts work 50% of the time.  Can someone please shed some light on this